# How to slice process itertools.product in python?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I want to process a very large `itertools.product` object. The issue is something like this:

```
import string
from itertools import product
text = string.lowercase[:] + string.uppercase[:] + '0123456789'
items = product(text, repeat=5)
for item in items:
    #do something
```

I know the `items`'s length is `62**5`. If I want to process the elements of `items` whose indices range from `300000` to `600000`, how to achieve this?

I have tried to convert the `itertools.product` to python list, like this:

```
items = list(product(text, repeat=5))[300000:600000+1]
for item in items:
    #do something
```

but it seems the conversion has consumed a large amount of memory since I have been waiting for a long time for this convert, and finally gave it up.

I have this demand because I want to do this thing in python gevent, so I want to slice the large `itertool.product` to small items for gevent spawn.

Comment: `itertools.product` is a generator function, so you should be able to iterate over it as is, without "eagerly" collecting it first in a list, tuple, or whatever. Oh, will edit the question, as it to mee reads misleading (but @ForceBru understood ;-) ...

Comment: You can take a look at `itertools.dropwhile` in collaboration with `itertools.takewhile`, but again, it may run extremely slow

Comment: Does this slice represent a meaningful subset? If so, you would be much better off directly producing _that subset_ using a Cartesian product.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to do this.

```
from itertools import product, islice
import string 

text = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
for item in islice(product(text,repeat=5), 300000, 600000):
    # do something
```

Comment: Wow, this runs really fast! But as I add more zeros at the end of the `start` and `stop` positions, it becomes slower and slower as Python has to 'manually' skip everything until the `start`th element (so, it doesn't magically start right from the beginning of this slice)...

Comment: @ForceBru this is because `islice`  consumes the iterator and discard the item up to the starting point.